# How to delete data form two tables values in JPA?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

```
@Query(Delete * from task INNER JOIN task_data where task.taskId = '2' and task_data.taskId = '2')
```

Comment: Why not use the cascade delete option in JPA. You can define the relationship with [@OneToMany with "orphanremoval = true"](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-cascade-remove-vs-orphanremoval)

Answer (score 1):

for native query we use nativeQuery = true

```
@Query("DELETE t.*, td.* FROM task t LEFT JOIN task_data td ON t.taskId = td.taskId WHERE t.taskId = 2, nativeQuery = true)
```

For more details
https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/444015/Single-SQL-Query-to-delete-records-in-two-tables

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any relationship b/w both the table you can achieve this by  writing two diff methods for that.

i.e you can do something following,

```
interface TaskRepo extends C..... {
    @Query(Delete * from task where task.taskId = :taskId)
    public void deleteTask(@Param("taskId") String taskId);
    
    @Query(Delete * from task_data where task.taskId = :taskId)
    public void deleteTaskData(@Param("taskId") String taskId);
    
    default delateTasks(String taskId) {
        deleteTask(taskId);
        deleteTaskData(taskId);
    }
}
```

You can call `deleteTasks()` method by passing taskId.

Answer (score 0):

```
in model :
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "task",orphanRemoval = true)
@JsonIgnore
private List<taskData> taskDataList= new ArrayList<>();
------------------------------------------------------------
@ManyToOne
@JsonIgnore
@JoinColumn(name = "taskId")
private Task task;
************************************************************
in controller : 
taskRepository.deleteById(taskId);
```